# How to filter data by matching currency code

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
[
  {
    code: 'A',
    currencies: [ 'USD' ],
  },
  {
    code: 'B',
    currencies: [ 'USD', 'PEN' ],
  }
]
```

I need to remove from `currencies` the value `USD` only when `code` = `B`

So the output should be:

```
[
  {
    code: 'A',
    currencies: [ 'USD' ],
  },
  {
    code: 'B',
    currencies: [ 'PEN' ],
  }
]
```

I'm trying this but I'm gettin an empty array.

https://jsfiddle.net/5sroy47a/

```js
const items = [{
    code: 'A',
    currencies: ['USD'],
  },
  {
    code: 'B',
    currencies: ['USD', 'PEN'],
  }
];

const itemFiltered = items.filter(item => {
  console.log('item', item);
  if (item.code === 'B') {
    let currencies = item.currencies;
    currencies = currencies.filter(currency => currency !== 'USD')
  }
});

console.log('itemFiltered: ', itemFiltered);
```

Comment: You have to assign the filtered list back to `item.currencies`.

Comment: Don't you want `items.map`? You want the output to be the same length, you're only filtering the *inner* array. `items.map(({ code, currencies }) => ({ code, currencies: code === "B" ? currencies.filter((currency) => currency !== "USD") : currencies }));`.

Comment: A problem I haven't seen anyone else mention is you're filtering the _outer_ list of items, and never returning anything in the filter function, hence, `itemFiltered` is always an empty array.

Comment: Just so you're aware that the example has no JSON, so I updated the title to match what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `Array.map()`.

```js
const items = [{
    code: 'A',
    currencies: ['USD'],
  },
  {
    code: 'B',
    currencies: ['USD', 'PEN'],
  }
];

const itemFiltered = items.map(item => {
  if (item.code === 'B') {
    item.currencies = item.currencies.filter(currency => currency !== 'USD')
  }
  return item
});

console.log('itemFiltered: ', itemFiltered);
```

Comment: If you use filter then you have to return the value [Demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/1e86rtbm/)

Answer (score 1):

for dynamic data you can try this

```js
const items = [{
    code: 'A',
    currencies: ['USD'],
  },
  {
    code: 'B',
    currencies: ['USD', 'PEN', 'KRW'],
  },
  {
    code: 'C',
    currencies: ['KRW', 'IDR', 'USD', 'PEN'],
  }
];

currenctFiltered = []
const itemFiltered = items.map(item => {
  item.currencies = item.currencies.filter(currency => {
    if (!currenctFiltered.includes(currency)) {
      currenctFiltered.push(currency)
      return currency;
    }
  })
  return item
});

console.log('itemFiltered: ', itemFiltered);
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter function adds a boolean filter.
It does not return the curencies array, unfortunately.
You can use the Map function to reach the lower arra. Since the map function returns you as an array, you have to convert it to a singular arra with Reduce. Afterwards, you can reach the result by applying your filter again.

```
const filtered=items.filter(item => item.code === 'B').map(m=>m.currencies).reduce(function(a, b){ return a.concat(b); }).filter(f=>f !== 'USD');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/metalsimyaci/ga94ukb7/